# How can i create javascript links so that google does not recognize them as links?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I want to create links on images through javascript in a way that Google does not recognize them as links. Any helpful answer would be appreciable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The right way to signal to a search engine not to crawl a link is with `ref='nofollow'`

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link text</a>
```

Comment: +1 good answer - tho, you still have to trust an engine it will follow that instruction.

Comment: This is good. Completely forgot it. +1 @jAndy: Then you have to hide the complete page behind captchas ;)

Comment: @Nippey: I don't get your point. If a crawler wants to spy the target of an *anchor* it will most likely look into the *href* property. Its very unlikely it will just read *any* property, how would it know which is the actual target.

Comment: If a user has things like the Google-Toolbar installed, the URL will be submitted to Google anyway, but in this case: Going around the 'nofollow' directive. The same applies if someone posts a link to your site in a forum.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want this?
If you don't want Google to index specific parts of your webpage, try to put a `robots.txt` in the root folder.

With this file, you can tell search engines, which folders they should index and which not.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

If any other page in the web links to the the page hidden behind the links, this will be enough for Google to find and index it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain what you mean with "not recognize", but if you want to "hide" the actual *URI*, you may bind a *click event handler* to an *anchor node* and redirect the browser via `location.href`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[ 0 ].addEventListener('click', function( e ) {
    location.href = this.getAttribute( 'data-myurl' );
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

The actualy HTML markup would look like

```
<a href='#' data-myurl='http://www.google.com'>click me</a>
```

Comment: You forgot to add `'click'` as first parameter to `addEventListener` and this does not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont really want/need the links (fallback for users without javascript), you could just strip the link tags and append your click handlers to the images.

before:

```
<a id="my-link" href=".."><img src="..."></a>

<script>
  document.getElementById('my-link').onClick = function() ...
</script>
```

after:

```
<img id="my-link" src="...">

<script>
  document.getElementById('my-link').onClick = function() ...
</script>
```